# Logging Into a site that uses Live.com authentication

Tags: c#, http, authentication, https

I've been trying to automate a log in to a website I frequent, www.bungie.net. The site is associated with Microsoft and Xbox Live, and as such makes uses of the Windows Live ID API when people log in to their site.

I am relatively new to creating web spiders/robots, and I worry that I'm misunderstanding some of the most basic concepts. I've simulated logins to other sites such as Facebook and Gmail, but live.com has given me nothing but trouble.

Anyways, I've been using Wireshark and the Firefox addon Tamper Data to try and figure out what I need to post, and what cookies I need to include with my requests. As far as I know these are the steps one must follow to log in to this site.

**1.** Visit https: //login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1268167141&rver=5.5.4177.0&wp=LBI&wreply=http:%2F%2Fwww.bungie.net%2FDefault.aspx&id=42917

**2.** Recieve the cookies MSPRequ and MSPOK.

**3.** Post the values from the form ID "PPSX", the values from the form ID "PPFT", your username, your password all to a changing URL similar to: https: //login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=
(there are a few numbers that change at the end of that URL)

**4.** Live.com returns the user a page with more hidden forms to post. The client then posts the values from the form "ANON", the value from the form "ANONExp" and the values from the form "t" to the URL: http ://www.bung ie.net/Default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

**5.** After posting that data, the user is returned a variety of cookies the most important of which is "BNGAuth" which is the log in cookie for the site.

Where I am having trouble is on fifth step, but that doesn't neccesarily mean I've done all the other steps correctly. I post the data from "ANON", "ANONExp" and "t" but instead of being returned a BNGAuth cookie, I'm returned a cookie named "RSPMaybe" and redirected to the home page.

When I review the Wireshark log, I noticed something that instantly stood out to me as different between the log when I logged in with Firefox and when my program ran. It could be nothing <del>but I'll include the picture here for you to review</del>. I'm being returned an HTTP packet from the site before I post the data in the fourth step. I'm not sure how this is happening, but it must be a side effect from something I'm doing wrong in the HTTPS steps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Web;

namespace SpiderFromScratch
{
    class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
            Uri url = new Uri("https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1268167141&rver=5.5.4177.0&wp=LBI&wreply=http:%2F%2Fwww.bungie.net%2FDefault.aspx&id=42917");
            HttpWebRequest http = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

            http.Timeout = 30000;
            http.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
            http.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            http.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
            http.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
            http.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "300");
            http.Referer = "http://www.bungie.net/";
            http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            http.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            http.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse();
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string HTML = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            readStream.Close();

            //gets the cookies (they are set in the eighth header)
            string[] strCookies = response.Headers.GetValues(8);
            response.Close();

            string name, value;
            Cookie manualCookie;
            for (int i = 0; i < strCookies.Length; i++)
            {
                name = strCookies[i].Substring(0, strCookies[i].IndexOf("="));
                value = strCookies[i].Substring(strCookies[i].IndexOf("=") + 1, strCookies[i].IndexOf(";") - strCookies[i].IndexOf("=") - 1);
                manualCookie = new Cookie(name, "\"" + value + "\"");

                Uri manualURL = new Uri("http://login.live.com");
                http.CookieContainer.Add(manualURL, manualCookie);
            }


            //stores the cookies to be used later
            cookies = http.CookieContainer;

            //Get the PPSX value
            string PPSX = HTML.Remove(0, HTML.IndexOf("PPSX"));
            PPSX = PPSX.Remove(0, PPSX.IndexOf("value") + 7);
            PPSX = PPSX.Substring(0, PPSX.IndexOf("\""));

            //Get this random PPFT value
            string PPFT = HTML.Remove(0, HTML.IndexOf("PPFT"));
            PPFT = PPFT.Remove(0, PPFT.IndexOf("value") + 7);
            PPFT = PPFT.Substring(0, PPFT.IndexOf("\""));

            //Get the random URL you POST to
            string POSTURL = HTML.Remove(0, HTML.IndexOf("https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct="));
            POSTURL = POSTURL.Substring(0, POSTURL.IndexOf("\""));


            //POST with cookies
            http = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(POSTURL);

            http.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
            http.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            http.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
            http.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
            http.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "300");
            http.CookieContainer = cookies;
            http.Referer = "https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1268158321&rver=5.5.4177.0&wp=LBI&wreply=http:%2F%2Fwww.bungie.net%2FDefault.aspx&id=42917";
            http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            http.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

            Stream ostream = http.GetRequestStream();

            //used to convert strings into bytes
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

            //Post information
            byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes("PPSX=" + PPSX +"&PwdPad=IfYouAreReadingThisYouHaveTooMuc&login=YOUREMAILGOESHERE&passwd=YOURWORDGOESHERE" +
            "&LoginOptions=2&PPFT=" + PPFT);
            ostream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            ostream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse();
            readStream = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream());
            HTML = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            response2.Close();
            ostream.Dispose();
            foreach (Cookie cookie in response2.Cookies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + ": ");
                Console.WriteLine(cookie.Value);
                Console.WriteLine(cookie.Expires);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            //SET POSTURL value
            string POSTANON = "http://www.bungie.net/Default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0";

            //Get the ANON value
            string ANON = HTML.Remove(0, HTML.IndexOf("ANON"));
            ANON = ANON.Remove(0, ANON.IndexOf("value") + 7);
            ANON = ANON.Substring(0, ANON.IndexOf("\""));
            ANON = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ANON);

            //Get the ANONExp value
            string ANONExp = HTML.Remove(0, HTML.IndexOf("ANONExp"));
            ANONExp = ANONExp.Remove(0, ANONExp.IndexOf("value") + 7);
            ANONExp = ANONExp.Substring(0, ANONExp.IndexOf("\""));
            ANONExp = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ANONExp);

            //Get the t value
            string t = HTML.Remove(0, HTML.IndexOf("id=\"t\""));
            t = t.Remove(0, t.IndexOf("value") + 7);
            t = t.Substring(0, t.IndexOf("\""));
            t = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(t);

            //POST the Info and Accept the Bungie Cookies
            http = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(POSTANON);

            http.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
            http.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            http.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
            http.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
            http.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
            http.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "115");
            http.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            http.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

            http.Expect = null;

            ostream = http.GetRequestStream();
            int test = ANON.Length;
            int test1 = ANONExp.Length;
            int test2 = t.Length;
            buffer = encoding.GetBytes("ANON=" + ANON +"&ANONExp=" + ANONExp + "&t=" + t);
            ostream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            ostream.Close();

            //Here lies the problem, I am not returned the correct cookies.
            HttpWebResponse response3 = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse();
            GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(response3.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress);
            readStream = new StreamReader(gzip);
            HTML = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            //gets both cookies
            string[] strCookies2 = response3.Headers.GetValues(11);

            response3.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an aside... another great tool for watching the wire is Fiddler.  Not sure how well wireshark stacks up to it, but one might catch something (https?) the other doesn't.

Comment: I'll have to check it out, I filtered out the SSL traffic in this one simply to illustrate the perculiarity I noticed. The way C# handles SSL is definitely different than the way Firefox handles it, and that could very well be the source of my problems too.
It seems like every time I make a request to a new page using SSL and C#, it has to reauthenticate.
I don't have enough experience in this area to know if that'd be a problem or not though.

Comment: I can recommend to also use the Firefox add-on called Firebug, then use its console tab with the option "Persist" on. You can see the detailed requests and responses for the authenticating proces of Live.com.

Comment: Surely there is a way to authenticate with Windows Live SDK without having to use web crawling / http posting etc etc? 

There's bound to be a webservice?

Comment: I've looked far and wide for one, but I haven't come across anything. To be honest, Microsoft seems to be going down the whole "security via obfuscation"  path on this one. Which makes sense, they probably don't want people automating tasks that use their live.com authentication.

Comment: Just as a matter of curiosity, why do you want to do this?  What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: The best way to do this is use httpanalyzer. Now called IE inspector, great to gather what you need to do what you are doing. I used to use it to scrape county data all over the US. It didn't do the scraping, but I was able to bot it using that tool. It is way better then fiddler and firebug for what you are trying to do. Remember an important thing is timing with your requests.

Comment: oh yeah here is the link:
http://ieinspector.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're still working on this or not but the Windows Live Development site has a lot of info on it to help with using the Live ID API.  I've not had much of a dig into it but their [Getting Started](http://dev.live.com/blogs/liveid/archive/2006/05/18/8.aspx) page has a load of info plus a link to download sample applications detailing how to use the service in a variety of languages (including C#).

You can download the sample application from there.

It sounds pretty interesting what you're trying to do, so much so that I quite fancy having a play with this myself!

Answer (score 0):

Change your timing and see if you get the same results.

Answer (score -2):

It is so much easier to just use a UI automation framework like WatiN than to use httpwebrequest, unless that would break your requirements.  With WatiN, you are thinking about what is shown on UI rather than what is on the HTML.

Comment: -1: if you read the code carefully, you'll see that he's not actually processing HTML at all.